# USD to GBP currency converter in PHP

Tags: php, api, google-api, currency

I am trying to make a currency converter using the Google API in PHP but it's giving me a blank page.

**index.php:**

```
<div id='output'></div>
<form action='convert.php' method='post'>
Amount: <input name='amount' type='text'><br/>
From: <select name='from'>
        <option value='USD'>USD</option>
        <option value='GBP'>GBP</option>
        </select><br/>
To: <select name='to'>
        <option value='GBP'>GBP</option>
        <option value='USD'>USD</option>
        </select><br/>
<input name='submit' type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

**convert.php:**

```
    <?php

function currency($from, $to, $amount) {
   $content = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a='.$amount.'&from='.$from.'&to='.$to);
   $doc = new DOMDocument;
   @$doc->loadHTML($content);
   $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
   $result = $xpath->query('//*[@id="currency_converter_result"]/span')->item(0)->nodeValue;
   return str_replace(' '.$to, '', $result);
}

if(!empty($_POST) && isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $output = currency($_POST['from'], $_POST['to'], $_POST['amount']);
    echo "<script>document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = '<p>" . $output . "</p>'></script>";
}

?>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: ...how do I make it work?

Comment: How is it not working? What do you expect and what do you get instead?

Answer (score 0):

It's blank because you're posting the data to a new page.

In *index.php* you have the line

```
<div id='output'></div>
```

which is where you expect the output to end up. But when you push submit on the form, you're actually going to an entirely different page. If you look at the url, it now ends in *convert.php*

If you click submit and take a look at the source of the page, it actually contains exactly the content you told it to.

Just replace line 14 in output.php with this:

```
echo $output;
```

You'll see your result then.

Since you expected the output to appear on the same page as the one where the form resides, you might want to look into using [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/).

Alternatively, you could put the logic for getting the result in the same page by doing something like the following:

```
<?php

function currency($from, $to, $amount) {
   $content = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a='.$amount.'&from='.$from.'&to='.$to);
   $doc = new DOMDocument;
   @$doc->loadHTML($content);
   $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
   $result = $xpath->query('//*[@id="currency_converter_result"]/span')->item(0)->nodeValue;
   return str_replace(' '.$to, '', $result);
}

if(!empty($_POST) && isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $output = currency($_POST['from'], $_POST['to'], $_POST['amount']);
}

?>

<div id='output'><?php if(isset($output)) { echo $output; } ?></div>
<form action='index.php' method='post'>
Amount: <input name='amount' type='text'><br/>
From: <select name='from'>
        <option value='USD'>USD</option>
        <option value='GBP'>GBP</option>
        </select><br/>
To: <select name='to'>
        <option value='GBP'>GBP</option>
        <option value='USD'>USD</option>
        </select><br/>
<input name='submit' type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: I replaced index.php with that and I'm still getting a blank page when I submit the form.

Comment: What is in the source of the blank page if you do "view source"?

Comment: Well, this is strange... I'm embedding the form with an iFrame on my website and the converter works perfectly there. But when I access the PHP file directly, it doesn't. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the parameters in below function that hits the Google URL and fetch the currency converted response.

Parameters:
`$from_Currency` = In which you want response.
`$to_Currency` = From which you need to convert.
`$amount` = Amount you want to convert.

```
<?php

function get_currency($from_Currency, $to_Currency, $amount) {

$amount = urlencode($amount);
$from_Currency = urlencode($from_Currency);
$to_Currency = urlencode($to_Currency);

$url = "http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from_Currency&to=$to_Currency";

$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 0;
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data = explode('bld>', $rawdata);
$data = explode($to_Currency, $data[1]);
return round($data[0], 2);
}

// Call the function to get the currency converted
echo get_currency('USD', 'INR', 1);

?>
```

Response:

> 65.24 (As per today rate of USD)

Answer (score 0):

Google has updated the link i.e. it has been moved to a new site. So this might be helpful :

```
function currencyConvert($from,$to,$amount){
    $url = "https://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from&to=$to";
    $request = curl_init(); 
    $timeOut = 0; 
    curl_setopt ($request, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt ($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

    curl_setopt ($request, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)"); 
    curl_setopt ($request, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeOut); 
    $response = curl_exec($request); 
    curl_close($request); 

        $rawdata = str_replace('</span>','',str_replace('<span class="bld">','',$response));
    list(,$val) = explode("bld>",$rawdata);
    list($raw2,) = explode("<input",$val);
    return (float) $raw2;
}
```

To call this function :

```
echo currencyConvert('USD','NPR',1);
```

This will convert $1 to Nepali Rupees.

Similar could be used for USD to GBP.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it's better use conversion through API becouse load all the page could be slow and imprevedible.

```
function convertCurrency($amount, $from, $to){
  $conv_id = "{$from}_{$to}";
  $string = file_get_contents("http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=$conv_id&compact=ultra");
  $json_a = json_decode($string, true);

  return $amount * round($json_a[$conv_id], 4);
}
//EXAMPLE convert 29 euro in $
echo(convertCurrency(29, "EUR", "USD"));
```

Answer (score 0):

*finance.google.com has been discontinued*, **try these**:

```
// google API - Load time: 558 ms
function google_money_convert($from, $to, $amount)
{
    $url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=".$from.$to;
    $request = curl_init();
    $timeOut = 0;
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36");
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeOut);
    $response = curl_exec($request);
    curl_close($request);

    preg_match('~<span [^>]* id="knowledge-currency__tgt-amount"[^>]*>(.*?)</span>~si', $response, $finalData);
    $finalData=str_replace(',', '.', $finalData);
    return (float)$finalData[1]*$amount;
}


 // free.currencyconverter API - Load time: 95ms
    function money_convert($from, $to, $amount)
{
    $url = "http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=$query&compact=ultra";
    $request = curl_init();
    $timeOut = 0;
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36");
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeOut);
    $response = curl_exec($request);
    curl_close($request);
    $response = json_decode($response, true);
    $responseOld=$response;
    // print_r($response);
    return $response[$query]*$amount;
}
```